# Play a sound on page load using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, onload

How can I play a sound file when the onload event fires using JavaScript?

**For example:**

If I have a webpage, when a user clicks on a button and this will pop-up a window. While the pop-up window is loading, the page will play a sound file.

Answer (score 7):

Add a HTML5 audio element into your document:

```
 <audio id="foobar" src="yoursample.ogg" preload="auto">
```

Set it hidden via CSS:

```
 #foobar { display: none }
```

On the any JavaScript event handler play the audio:

```
var sample = document.getElementById("foobar");
sample.play();
```

For more information

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_HTML5_audio_and_video

Depending on your web application purpose you might want to support old browsers:

http://www.misfitgeek.com/play-sound-in-html5-and-cross-browser-support-with-backward-compatability/

Comment: Please, note that Chrome doesn't allow media autoplay since April 2018 unless the user interact with the webage first and other conditions details here : https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
//store the audiofile as variable.
var popupsound = document.getElementById("notifypop");

function autoNotify() {
   popupsound.play(); //play the audio file
}
```

```css
#notifypop{ display:none;}
```

```html
<body onload="autoNotify()"> <!--Play the audio file on pageload  -->

  <audio id="notifypop"> <!--Source the audio file. -->
            <source src="path/sound.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
            <source src="path/sound.mpeg" type="audio/mpeg">
  </audio>
  
  <script  src="path/sound.js" type="text/javascript"></script><!--Load your javascript sound file.-->
  
</body>
```

Learn more about HTML5 media formats 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Supported_media_formats

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it would be to insert HTML audio tags onclick and set them to automatically start:

http://webdesign.about.com/od/sound/a/play_sound_oncl.htm