# Play an alarm with the table value in webapge

Tags: javascript, php, html, audio

I have a webpage containing a table that auto-refresh everytime & updates the table values. I want to add an alarm when the table value reached a threshold value so I don't have to look at the table always. what is the best possible way to do this?
My webpage is updating data using PHP. I know this is somewhat possible using javascript. Also, I found there is a limitation in doing this without a user gesture

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found another post with something similar and if your refreshing all the time then you could make a PHP if else statement to check database values and run the audio.

if ($value > 10){play audio}else{nothing}

[Play a sound on page load using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12631420/play-a-sound-on-page-load-using-javascript)